# Can node.js or electron automate other desktop applications?

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible to automate other desktop applications using node.js and/or electron? In other words, I'd like to do the following workflow, from an Electron application:

1. Start a specific application
2. Maximize it
3. Capture the screen
4. Close the application

I just need somewhere to start. It's a hard thing to search for.

Comment: Depends on other application capabilities, i.e., NodeJS can run commands as mentioned in the [link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback). If you need full control of other application then try UiPath or Automation Anyware

Answer (score 0):

Selenium JS has experimental support to automate desktop GUI. It requires you to have WinAppDriver server running and passing the capabilities to WebDriver as mentioned below.

```
let driver: WebDriver = await new Builder()
  .usingServer("http://127.0.0.1:47")
  .withCapabilities({ app: "path to the application" })
  .forBrowser("windows")
  .build();
await this.sessionWaitTime(driver, 5);
await driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(seconds);
await driver.manage().window().maximize();
await driver.quit();
```

In case, if you are trying to automate larger chunks then you may need UI inspector such as inspect.exe or UI Spy to investigate desktop GUI elements and locate it using selenium 'findElement' APIs.